# spring boot, jpa, custom query(LOAD), upload csv to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

is it possible?? that

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long> {
    @Query("LOAD DATA LOCAL FILE ?1 INTO ......")
    public void loadCsv(String filePath);
}
```

because I have to move a lot of data(1M~ rows) to mysql table.

I found some ways for moving data and I am sure LOAD query is fastest. if any guys have any way for solving this problem, please give me advice!

thanks. :)

Comment: Yes you can do native query but not this way.

Comment: how to use native query with jpa naturelly?

Comment: I also got the same issue.

I tried doing the following:

 `@Query (value="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/tester/Documents/transaction_data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_fin FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES", nativeQuery = true)
 public void bulkLoadData();
`
However I get the following error.

`java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.`

Looking this error up on google, forums have said that this is because the query is not returning data and it should be placed in a stored procedur but MySQL does not allow LOAD DATA commands in a stored procedure. Any thoughts?

Comment: @rm12345 did you find any solution ? we got same issue

Comment: @Krish you can see my solution on the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209785/spring-boot-jpa-use-library-to-bulk-load-data-for-mysql

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass the location of the file on DB server for below query, not the application server.
`@Query("LOAD DATA LOCAL FILE ?1 INTO ......")`

Comment: This is too short. Please elaborate how this solves the problem described in the question at the top of this page.